# Ubuntu preseed static IP configuration (virt-install)

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, preseed

I want to create Ubuntu 14.04 VM with virt-install and preseed configuration.
I have provided:

```
d-i netcfg/enable boolean true
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto
d-i netcfg/disable_dhcp boolean true
d-i netcfg/get_ipaddress string 192.168.1.210
d-i netcfg/get_netmask string /24
d-i netcfg/get_gateway string 192.168.1.254
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string ubuntu.com
d-i netcfg/get_nameservers string 8.8.8.8
d-i netcfg/confirm_static boolean true
```

But anyway I have another ip in guest VM. Need your help

Answer (score 2):

To disable dhcp you need to have `disable_autoconfig` and **not** `disable_dhcp`:

```
d-i netcfg/disable_autoconfig boolean true
```

The netmask declartion looks also wrong. Try this instead:

`d-i netcfg/get_netmask string 255.255.255.0`

Check here for complete ref: [B.4. Contents of the preconfiguration file (for trusty)](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/armhf/apbs04.html)

```
# If you prefer to configure the network manually, uncomment this line and
# the static network configuration below.
#d-i netcfg/disable_autoconfig boolean true

# Static network configuration.
#d-i netcfg/get_nameservers string 192.168.1.1
#d-i netcfg/get_ipaddress string 192.168.1.42
#d-i netcfg/get_netmask string 255.255.255.0
#d-i netcfg/get_gateway string 192.168.1.1
#d-i netcfg/confirm_static boolean true
```

Comment: All exactly the same. Ip was assigned from DHCP

Comment: What do you mean? doesn't work? Then add this too and see `d-i netcfg/dhcp_options select Configure network manually`

Comment: Yes, this doesn't work, my config

   `d-i netcfg/enable boolean true`
    `d-i netcfg/choose_interface select eth0`
   ` d-i netcfg/disable_autoconfig boolean true`

    `d-i netcfg/dhcp_failed note`
    `d-i netcfg/dhcp_options select Configure network manually`
    `d-i netcfg/get_ipaddress string 192.168.1.222`
    `d-i netcfg/get_netmask string /24`
   `d-i netcfg/get_gateway string 192.168.1.254`
   `d-i netcfg/get_hostname string ubuntu3.com`
`d-i netcfg/get_nameservers string 8.8.8.8`
`d-i netcfg/confirm_static boolean true`

Comment: @VladimirKovalchuk, change two more lines and see: `d-i netcfg/get_netmask string 255.255.255.0` and `d-i netcfg/get_hostname string ubuntu` (you can't use . in hostname)